# Why is ReSharper suggesting a possible NullReferenceException on a dynamic type?

Tags: c#, dynamic, resharper, nullreferenceexception

If I write the following code, ReSharper is warning me for a possible `NullReferenceException`. However I'm explicitly checking for `null` in the statement above.  Is there something about `dynamic` I do not know about (is it assuming it might be backed by a `IEnumerable` or something like that)? Or is this a glitch with ReSharper? Or something else?

```cs
dynamic user = connection.Query("SELECT ...").FirstOrDefault(); // Dapper Extension
if (user == null)
    return null;

return new User(user.username);
//              ^^^^
// (local variable) dynamic user
//
// Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

Comment: Can the problem be in `connection.Query("SELECT ...") = null`?

Comment: @Dmitry I do not think so, as the problem is not in runtime.

Comment: I've seen this a couple of times and just assumed it was a flaw in ReSharper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `user == null` is a dynamic call; R# can't assume that the runtime type of the `user` object will have an equality operator that works properly. It could very easily have:

```
public static bool operator ==(Foo x, Foo y) { return false; }
public static bool operator !=(Foo x, Foo y) { return true; }
```

in which case, `user == null` would always return `false`, even if the `user` variable was a `null` reference.

Try changing the code to:

```
if (ReferenceEquals(user, null)) return null;
return new User(user.username);
```

*NB: The problem only appears when you have the "Assume entity value can be null" option set to "When entity doesn't have explicit NotNull attribute".*

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
dynamic user = connection.Query("SELECT ...").FirstOrDefault(); // Dapper Extension
if (user != null)
    return new User(user.username);

return null;
```